# Minikube doesn't start on Mac with VPN

Tags: macos, ssh, kubernetes, virtualbox, minikube

I am trying to start a Minikube cluster locally on Mac0S with Cisco AnyConnectVPN

```
minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox
```

I keep getting the following error:

[image]

Strangely

```
minikube ssh
```

is working :o

Is there a way I could turn this ssh verification off for minikube start?

Answer (score 2):

Minikube needs to connect to the minikube vm to be able to start and stop it correctly and do most of the `minikube <cmd>` commands, e.g. `minikube addons list`.
So you are not able to start the vm correctly if minikube can't connect.

So you can:

- use hyperkit as a vm driver
- try to change the network configuration of the vm in virtualbox.